# How to manage controller scope inside directive for particular event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have defined scope object in controller called as

```
      $scope.labelEdit.Data  = {'lblCtrlEdit' : false, 'lblCtrlView' : true, 'inputShow': ''};
```

I'm accessing this scope inside directive inside directive(child directives). i am able to access.

My requirement is want to display the label or input based in scope value.
   for example : directive code

```
bosAppModule.directive('webFactoryCellControlLabel',function($compile, $timeout, webFactoryEvents){
    var layoutTableCellControlLabelObj={};

    linkFnTableCellControlLabel=function(scope, element, attributes, controllerCtrl) {
        //console.log("## webFactoryCellControlLabel");
        scope.labelData="";     
        scope.lblShow = true;
        scope.hideLblEditing = function () {
           $timeout(function() {                
               scope.labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlEdit = false; 
                scope.labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlView = true; 

            }, 2000);  // 2000ms delay   

        };
    };

    layoutTableCellControlLabelObj.scope={controlId:'=',attributeId:'=',layoutData:'=',pageObject:'=', cellId:'=',lblProperties: '=', attrModel: '=', labelCtrlEdit:'=', lblShow: '='};
    layoutTableCellControlLabelObj.restrict='AE';
    layoutTableCellControlLabelObj.replace='true';
    layoutTableCellControlLabelObj.transclude='true';
    layoutTableCellControlLabelObj.template = "<div "
            + "layout-data='layoutData' "
            + "page-object='pageObject' "
            + "label-ctrl-edit ='labelCtrlEdit'"            
            + "class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6' "
            + "style='padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-top: 0;' "             
            + ">" 
            + "<label ng-show='labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlView' class='k-label pull-right control-label' style='padding-top: 8px'><div><span style='{{setLabelStyle()}}'>{{labelData}}</span> &nbsp;  : &nbsp; &nbsp; </div></label>"
            + "<div ng-if='cellId == labelCtrlEdit.inputShow'>"
            +" <input focus-on='labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlEdit'  ng-show='labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlEdit' type='text' ng-mouseleave='hideLblEditing()' style='margin-right: 10px' class='k-textbox pull-right' ng-model='pageObject.collections.objectattribute.rowset[attrIndex].objectattributelabelname'/> "
            +"</div>"
            + "</div>";

    layoutTableCellControlLabelObj.link = linkFnTableCellControlLabel;


    return layoutTableCellControlLabelObj;  
});
```

In the above code has template in that i want to display label or input based scope values. It's working but it's taking for all label because scope value changing in two way binding.
   How can i achieve for particular cell only getting change.

```
bosAppModule.directive('webFactoryCell',function($compile,$timeout, webFactoryEvents){

    var containerCellObj={};

    linkFnContainerCell = function(scope, element, attributes) {    

        var bindingtypeid = scope.cell.weblayoutcellbindingtypeid;
        scope.cellclass='';
        scope.cellProperties = {};
        if(scope.selectedDevice=="ipad"){
            //update the we
        }

        if(scope.cell.weblayoutcellsubcontainer=="false"){
            switch (bindingtypeid) {
            case "43334FBD-23A7-42E9-B737-88642E2F8BB1":
                //console.log("## NORMAL CONTROL");
                //scope.cellclass='webcell webnormalcellstyle col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-3';
                //NORMAL CONTROL
                /*angular.forEach(scope.layoutData.collections.webcontainer.rowset,function(containerValue,containerKey){
                if(containerValue.webcontainerid==scope.cell.weblayoutcellcontainerid) {*/

                    element.append("<web-factory-cell-control " 
                            + "ng-if='cellcontrol.layouttablecellcontrolcellid==cell.weblayoutcellid' "
                            + " ng-repeat='cellcontrol in layoutData.collections.layouttablecellcontrol.rowset' " 
                            + "control-id='cellcontrol.layouttablecellcontrolcontroltypeid' "                   
                            + "cell-controldata='cellcontrol'"  
                            + "label-ctrl-edit ='labelCtrlEdit'"                            
    //                      + " cellclass={{cellclass}} "
                            + "></web-factory-cell-control>");
                /*  }
                });*/

                break;


            default:
                break;
            }



        }


        scope.cellClick=function(event){
            //console.log("jfksdjfjs"+event.target.data.class+$(event.target).attr("class"));

            webFactoryEvents.setWebFactoryEventsData({selectedCellId:$(event.target).closest(".webcell").attr("id")});
            var eventsDataObj = webFactoryEvents.getWebFactoryEventsData();         
            var attributeId =  $('#'+ eventsDataObj.selectedCellId).find('label').parent('div').attr('attrid');
            if(attributeId) {
                webFactoryEvents.setWebFactoryEventsData({selectedCellId:eventsDataObj.selectedCellId,
                                                          attributeId:attributeId});
            }


            webFactoryEvents.cellClickEvent(event);


            if(eventsDataObj.selectedCellId == scope.cell.weblayoutcellid) {
                scope.labelCtrlEdit.inputShow = eventsDataObj.selectedCellId;
                scope.labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlView = true;
            }


        };



        scope.labelControlEditing = function() {    
                scope.labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlEdit = true; 
                //scope.labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlView = false;
                //scope.labelCtrlEdit.inputShow = false;
                $timeout(function() {   
                    scope.$broadcast('labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlEdit');
                }, 10);
        };



        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };

    //containerCellObj.transclude='true';
    containerCellObj.restrict='AE';
    containerCellObj.replace='true';
    containerCellObj.scope={layoutData:'=',pageObject:'=',mapperData:'=',cell:'=',cellclass:'=',selectedDevice:'=',labelCtrlEdit:'='};
    containerCellObj.template = "<div "
            + "layout-data='layoutData' "
            + "page-object='pageObject' "
            + "mapper-data='mapperData' "   
            + "selected-device='selectedDevice' "
            + "label-ctrl-edit ='labelCtrlEdit'"        
//          + "class='webcell webcellstyle col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-3' " 
            + "ng-class='getCellClass()' " 
            + " cellid='{{cell.weblayoutcellid}}' " 
            + " id='{{cell.weblayoutcellid}}' "
            + " ng-click='cellClick($event)' "
            + " ng-dblclick='cellDblClick($event)' "            
            + " > " 
//          + "{{cell.weblayoutcellorderno}}##Cell{{cell.weblayoutcellid}}"
            + "<div class='webcell-settings webcontrol-settings'" 
            + " ng-class='{commandcellhandle:(cell.weblayoutcellbindingtypeid ==\"0d430cc8-7d7e-4fbb-8ba0-67b7fb9605fa\"),cellhandle:(cell.weblayoutcellbindingtypeid !=\"0d430cc8-7d7e-4fbb-8ba0-67b7fb9605fa\")}' "
            + ">" 
            + " <ul><li>"
            +"<a><i id='editlabel' class='fa fa-pencil' ng-click='labelControlEditing()'></i></a>"          
            +"<a><i id='repeat' class='fa fa-repeat disabledfornow' ></i></a>"
            +"<a><i id='trash' class='fa fa-trash-o' ></i></a>"
            +"<a><i id='up' class='fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up disabledfornow' ></i></a>"
            +"<a><i id='down' class='fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down disabledfornow' ></i></a>"
            +"<a><i id='edit' class='fa fa-gear' ></i></a>"
            +"</li> </ul>" 
            + "</div>"
            + "</div>";

    containerCellObj.link = linkFnContainerCell;

    return containerCellObj;    
});
```

Comment: can you clarify your question a bit? are your values changing because they're changing in controller and that is reflected in your directive too?

Comment: @boroboris ...propably yes but I'm only changing scope for a particular cell using click event . It's should change corresponding cell but it's changing for all cell because I'm changing scope. So I'm asking how to make that scope changes to apply only particular cell when ever click event if happening on that. Simply I can tell I need to achieve show and hide for particular cell not for whole. Main thing is cell click is happening parent directive and label or input (inside cell) having child directive.Please let me know I you need more clarification.

Comment: can you post your code for creating a click event? so this directive represents one cell? and when you change data in one you want that code to be changed just in that one directive/cell not in all of them?

Comment: @boroboris - Yes correct... i have place the click event code bottom. please have a look.

Comment: I've updated the answer. please take a look

Comment: @boroboris - I'm not able to find your changes . please mention any comment line description inside my code

Comment: I've added comments that explain what was changed.

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking I think the easiest way to solve that problem is to add new variable to each cell. I've named mine `cellValue`. After that we copy model value to that variable and we read it from that variable from now on. 
I've added method copyOrClone which just returns a variable (javascript passes variables by value and objects by reference) or object copy in case we've passed the object. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object).

```
bosAppModule.directive('webFactoryCellControlLabel',function($compile, $timeout, webFactoryEvents){

var layoutTableCellControlLabelObj={};

linkFnTableCellControlLabel=function(scope, element, attributes, controllerCtrl) {
scope.labelData="";
scope.lblShow = true;

scope.hideLblEditing = function () {
  $timeout(function() {
  scope.labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlEdit = false;
  scope.labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlView = true;
}, 2000);

};
};

layoutTableCellControlLabelObj.scope={
controlId:'=',attributeId:'=',layoutData:'=',
pageObject:'=', cellId:'=',lblProperties: '=', 
attrModel: '=', labelCtrlEdit:'=', lblShow: '=', 
cellValue:'='}; // this is new. value of the cell independent of value change in other cell directives. we get cell value from this variable

linkFnTableCellControlLabel=function(scope, element, attributes, controllerCtrl) {

    // you need this to clone objects
    // copy or clone object function
    function copyOrClone(obj) {
        if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
        var copy = obj.constructor();
        for (var attr in obj) {
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
        }
        return copy;
    }


    scope.labelData="";     
    scope.lblShow = true;
    scope.hideLblEditing = function () {
       $timeout(function() {                
           scope.labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlEdit = false; 
            scope.labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlView = true; 

        }, 2000);  // 2000ms delay   

    };

    // newly added variable to help in copying object passed trough directive
    var temporaryVariableOrObject = pageObject.collections.objectattribute.rowset[attrIndex].objectattributelabelname;
    scope.cellValue = copyOrClone(temporaryVariableOrObject);
};




layoutTableCellControlLabelObj.template = "<div cell-value='cellValue'"
        + "layout-data='layoutData' "
        + "page-object='pageObject' "
        + "label-ctrl-edit ='labelCtrlEdit'"            
        + "class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6' "
        + "style='padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-top: 0;' "             
        + ">" 
        + "<label ng-show='labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlView' class='k-label pull-right control-label' style='padding-top: 8px'><div><span style='{{setLabelStyle()}}'>{{labelData}}</span> &nbsp;  : &nbsp; &nbsp; </div></label>"
        + "<div ng-if='cellId == labelCtrlEdit.inputShow'>"
        +" <input focus-on='labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlEdit'  ng-show='labelCtrlEdit.lblCtrlEdit' type='text' ng-mouseleave='hideLblEditing()' style='margin-right: 10px' class='k-textbox pull-right' ng-model='cellValue'/> "   // changed model to cellValue
        +"</div>"
```

Comment: actually it's not my requirement

Comment: I'm only changing scope for a particular cell using click event . It's should change corresponding cell but it's changing for all cell because I'm changing scope. So I'm asking how to make that scope changes to apply only particular cell when ever click event if happening on that. Simply I can tell I need to achieve show and hide for particular cell not for whole. Main thing is cell click is happening parent directive and label or input (inside cell) having child directive.Please let me know I you need more clarification.